# How do I redirect asp page with params

Tags: asp.net, redirect, parameters

I am working on some 301 redirects from an old asp site to a new php one.

I now bumped into a problem and hoped someone would know:

How do I redirect asp pages with parameters to different landing pages, dependent on those parameters?

Example:

```
http://www.olddomain.co.uk/temp.asp?tn=619&Cat=<cat_a>Personalised Work
```

should go to

```
http://newdomain.com/12-personalised-work
```

but

```
http://www.olddomain.co.uk/temp.asp?ID=450&Cat=<cat_a>Personalised Designs
```

should go to

```
http://thomasnayler.com/13-personalised-designs
```

As you see, both call temp.asp, but with different params.

N.B. For straight forward pages I use this:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently" 
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://newdomain.com/page_name"
Response.End
%>
```

Any Idea?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are working in Classic ASP and not ASP.NET.  Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest getting the query string. Then check if there is a certain substring in there

```
dim theString
theString = Request.QueryString("Cat")

if instr(theString, "Personalised Designs")
then 
Response.Redirect "http://thomasnayler.com/13-personalised-designs"
else
Response.Redirect "http://thomasnayler.com/12-personalised-work"
```

Comment: This would be at the top of temp.asp, right? Thanks, that might work :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks, Matthew :-)